# Clear all "pages" cache

Tags: 8, caching

Is there a way on Drupal 8 to clear all "pages" cache or all "nodes" pages?

I was thinking about a custom drush command but I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: You might want to elaborate here on what you're referencing here. Drupal has many different caches. Are you talking about all assets in the page render pipeline (e.g. CSS, JS, node data, etc.) or just a certain type of node cache. Look at the `cache_*` tables to get an idea of what Drupal is caching.

Comment: I'm working on a "cache warmer" script, so I want to clear cache of every node/NID path. I don't know the right way is to invalidate "node:nid" cache tag. The idea was to run an entityquery to retrieve nids (or a subset of nids) and then invalidate cache.

Comment: However the answer is invalidate the node:NID cache tag for every node

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the settings documented in example.settings.local.php then you can easily see the cache tags that are present on a page.

What you will see then is that each rendered node has the `node_view` cache tag, so you only need to invalidate that.

There's also the 'rendered' cache tag which as added to any render cached item.

I don't quite understand why your cache warmer needs to invalidate the cache first, shouldn't be a problem if it's already warm? Drupal will automatically invalidate something if it is no longer valid.

The internal page cache also has no time limit by default.